# Repoze.bfg or Grok

Tags: python, plone, zope

I am about to take the head long plunge into Zope land and am wondering which framework would fit my needs better. I have some experience toying around with django and the primary reason I am switching to a zope-based framework is ZPT and also needing to occasionally do things with Plone. Both seem to be well run projects I am mainly wondering which would have the better learning overlap with Plone? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BFG doesn't have very much to do with Zope, except:

- it uses some Zope libraries internally.
- it uses a variant of ZPT as its built-in templating language.
- it uses some concepts, such as traversal, that will be familiar to Zope people.

If you know Zope 3 very well, and you like it, you'll like Grok.  If you want a framework maybe a bit more like Pylons, but slightly cleaner, and which uses some Zope technologies and concepts, you'll like BFG.

Comment: What if I will also be dealing with python novices?

Answer (score 0):

So Repoze.bfg advertises "pay for only what you eat", meaning that you can pick and choose what portions of the framework you need to include, and you don't have extra cruft in your app.

It looks like you can mix Plone and Repoze.bfg: [Here's a link to a Plone 2008 coference talk](http://plone.org/events/conferences/2008-washington-dc/agenda/repoze.bfg-a-zope-explosion), and the templating language matches ZPT too.

But, it's very possible that the community around Zope is bigger, and certainly has been established longer: it may just depend on your confort level. You might want to write a small app in each and see how you feel.